# My scraper throws an error clicking on the first link out of many

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to click on `a` tags under class `domino-viewentry` in a webpage. My script is able to click on the first `a` tag. However, instead of going for the next ones to click, it throws an error. My script and errors are given below. I hope somebody will take a look and provide me with any solution to make it right.

Link to the webpage: [webpage_link](http://www.siicex-caaarem.org.mx/Bases/TIGIE2007.nsf/4caa80bd19d9258006256b050078593c/)

My script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("above_link")

for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".domino-viewentry a"))):
    item.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))

driver.quit()
```

The error I'm having:

```
line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)
```

Comment: so you're trying to: click `01` then scrape its sub-content, then click `02` then scrape its content... and so on?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want your script to do? Just to click all those links or scrape some data?

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your availability. I only expect my script to click cyclically on different `a` tags under `domino-viewentry` class names and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to click all the links on page to expand embedded data you can use below code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.siicex-caaarem.org.mx/Bases/TIGIE2007.nsf/4caa80bd19d9258006256b050078593c/")

while True:
    try:
        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[img[@src='/icons/expand.gif'] and not(./following::img[@src='/icons/collapse.gif'])]")))
        link.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))
    except:
        break
```

But note that page is "not scalable": once you reached 01 > 02 > 0207 all following links just disappears, so you cannot continue... Let me know if you need to implement more complex logic

*Update*

If you want to click only "first level" links you can try:

```
links_length = len(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@colspan='9']//a[img]"))))

for index in range(links_length):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@colspan='9']//a[img]")[index].click()
```

Comment: Oh my god!! Your script keep going deeper clicking on and on. My expectation is very simple: only clicking on those visible right arrows. When one arrow is clicked then go for the next one (not including those sub arrows under the first one). See the link:[dropbox_link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyysoa4kyaowig6/Untitled.jpg?dl=0). Only the arrows visible (when nothing is clicked). btw, I'm accepting this answer in advance cause you have already used complex logic beyond my expectation.

Comment: This is so damn nice, sir Andersson. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So when you click the first link, you go to a different page, and references to the other elements in the first page are no longer valid, unfortunately. You would have to re-query the DOM to find the elements every time you load the page. See also: http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

For your purposes, you might be better off grabbing all the href's, storing those, and visiting them one by one to do your scraping.